# Powershell get-server -exclude those in a list

Tags: powershell

I have to query 400+ servers to find the business applications/services installed,there is no need for all the default services.

I obtained a list of services from a default system and put those in a **csv** file, but it doesn't seem to want to exclude them. Here is what I have so far:

```
{$excludelist = "c:\powershell\service_name.csv"
get-service -ComputerName servername -Exclude $excludelist
| Out-File C:\PowerShell\services.txt}
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Answer (score 0):

after trying this myself …  Ifound that the exclude property wants the name of the service:

```
get-service -Exclude (get-service w*).name
```

Could it be that you are getting more than just the name?

Answer (score 0):

Its going to depend on how the CSV is structured. If its simply a list of names you can use Get-Content, as in:

```
Get-Content -Path $Excludelist

get-service -ComputerName servername -Exclude (Get-Content -Path $Excludelist) | Out-File C:\PowerShell\services.txt
```

If the CSV is actually a structured CSV, you can use Import-CSV but the property name will depend on the structure.

```
get-service -ComputerName servername -Exclude (Import-CSV -Path $Excludelist).name | Out-File C:\PowerShell\services.txt
```

Use get-help to understand what type of data a parameter expects.

```
Get-Help Get-Service -Parameter ComputerName
-ComputerName <String[]>
    Gets the services running on the specified computers. The default is the local computer.

    Type the NetBIOS name, an IP address, or a fully qualified domain name of a remote computer. To specify the local
    computer, type the computer name, a dot (.), or "localhost".

    This parameter does not rely on Windows PowerShell remoting. You can use the ComputerName parameter of Get-Service
    even if your computer is not configured to run remote commands.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    named
    Default value                Local computer
    Accept pipeline input?       true (ByPropertyName)
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

In this case its an array of strings (or a single string).

Comment: Please note this get-contents your entire exclude list each round. And if you do a for loop it will slow down. Better to get it via variable. `$variable = (import-csv c:\exclude.csv).name`